# Training CNN with transfer learning in Keras - image input doesn't work but vector input does

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do transfer learning in Keras. I set up a ResNet50 network set to not trainable with some extra layers:

```
# Image input
model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg')) # output is 2048
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
model.layers[0].trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Then I create input data: `x_batch` using the ResNet50 `preprocess_input` function, along with the one hot encoded labels `y_batch` and do the fitting as so:

```
model.fit(x_batch,
          y_batch,
          epochs=nb_epochs,
          batch_size=64,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_split=0.2,
          callbacks=[lrate])
```

Training accuracy gets close to 100% after ten or so epochs, but validation accuracy actually decreases from around 50% to 30% with validation loss steadily increasing.

However if I instead create a network with just the last layers:

```
# Vector input
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dropout(0.05, input_shape=(2048,)))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.15))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.summary()
```

and feed in the output of the ResNet50 prediction:

```
resnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg')
x_batch = resnet.predict(x_batch)
```

Then validation accuracy gets up to around 85%... What is going on? Why won't the image input method work?

Update:

This problem is really bizarre. If I change ResNet50 to VGG19 it seems to work ok.

Comment: Check the number of trainable layers in the first case and in the second case. Are they the same?

Comment: @dgumo yes, they are the same

Comment: Yes the number of trainable parameters match (something like 24 million parameters, 23 million not trainable, 1.3 million trainable)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling I found that the problem is to do with the Batch Normalisation layers in ResNet. There are no batch normalisation layers in VGGNet which is why it works for that topology.

There is a pull request to fix this in Keras [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9965), which explains in more detail:

> Assume we use one of the pre-trained CNNs of Keras and we want to fine-tune it. Unfortunately, we get no guarantees that the mean and variance of our new dataset inside the BN layers will be similar to the ones of the original dataset. As a result, if we fine-tune the top layers, their weights will be adjusted to the mean/variance of the new dataset. Nevertheless, during inference the top layers will receive data which are scaled using the mean/variance of the original dataset. This discrepancy can lead to reduced accuracy.

This means that the BN layers are adjusting to the training data, however when validation is performed, the original parameters of the BN layers are used. From what I can tell, the fix is to allow the frozen BN layers to use the updated mean and variance from training.

A work around is to pre-compute the ResNet output. In fact, this decreases training time considerably, as we are not repeating that part of the calculation.

Comment: can explain more, `Batch normalisation` is a layer , is it there automatically in the first or the second case? and can you give the link for the fixed fork

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
Res = keras.applications.resnet.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
              weights='imagenet',  input_shape=(IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE , 3 ) )


    # Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers  :
   layer.trainable = False

# Check the trainable status of the individual layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)

# Vector input
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Res)
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dropout(0.05 ))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.15))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
model2.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics =(['accuracy'])
model2.summary()
```

Comment: May I understand why vgg_conv.layers are here for ResNet50 please.